# Strange use of the mean value into the definition of operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, linear-algebra

I am currently working on quantum mechanical wave packets and minimum uncertainty states, to be specific I am trying to prove that the minimum uncertainty state is represented by a gaussian.
Anyway, I was following the argument reported on my textbook when I stumbled upon the following definition of the operators $\Delta \hat{x} , \Delta \hat{p}$:
$$\Delta \hat{x}=\hat{x}-\langle \hat{x}\rangle$$
$$\Delta \hat{p}=\hat{p}-\langle \hat{p}\rangle$$
It's here that I have a problem: in my book is stated that $\Delta \hat{x},\Delta \hat{p}$ are operators so $\hat{x}-\langle \hat{x}\rangle,\hat{p}-\langle \hat{p}\rangle$ must also be operators; but $\hat{x},\hat{p}$ are operators in the Hilbert space and $\langle \hat{x}\rangle,\langle \hat{p}\rangle$ from what I understand are real numbers (the mean value):
$$\langle \hat{x}\rangle=\langle \psi|\hat{x}|\psi\rangle$$
$$\langle \hat{p}\rangle=\langle \psi|\hat{p}|\psi\rangle$$
But it has no meaning to add or subtract operators and numbers right? $\hat{x}-5$ is not a valid expression for an operator, so what is going on here?

Another possibility is to interprete $\langle \hat{x}\rangle,\langle \hat{p}\rangle$ as operators such that:
$$\langle \hat{x}\rangle |\psi\rangle=\langle \psi|\hat{x}|\psi\rangle$$
$$\langle \hat{p}\rangle |\psi\rangle=\langle \psi|\hat{p}|\psi\rangle$$
but this would make them operators of the kind:
$$A:H \to \mathbb{R}$$
($H$: Hilbert space)
whereas $\hat{x},\hat{p}$ are of the kind:
$$A:H\to H$$
and like before it has no meaning to sum or subtract them, since they operate on different spaces. Furthermore I am not even sure that you can interprete $\langle \hat{x}\rangle,\langle \hat{p}\rangle$ as operators..

What is going on here? What do we mean with $\Delta \hat{x} , \Delta \hat{p}$? Why this subtraction between operators-numbers (or different kinds of operators maybe) are allowed? I feel like I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Number is understood as the identity operator multiplied by this number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is meant by that expression is

$\Delta\hat{x}=\hat{x}-\langle\hat{x}\rangle \text{Id}$,

with $\text{Id}$ being the identity operator.